# Restrict Back Button React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I would like to restrict access to my router and disabled the back button.

For example, if the user manually types on the browser tab or click in an URL besides `event/:eventId`, I want to redirect it to `event/:eventId`

Current:

1. The user visits `event/1234/friends`.
2. It gets redirected to `event/1234`
3. The user clicks the back button and is be able to see  `event/1234/friends`. (It should **not** be able to visit `event/1234/friends`).

Note: This bug only happens on mobile. You can't reproduce it on desktop.

Desired:

1. The user visits `event/1234/friends`.
2. It gets redirected to `event/1234`
3. Disable the back button or if the user clicks the back button, won't be able to visit  `event/1234/friends`

This how my code looks like

```
 const eventPathname = props.history?.location?.pathname;
  const matches = eventPathname.match(/^\/event\/([^/]+)\/.+$/);
  if (!!matches) {
    const defaultPathname = `/event/${matches[1]}`;
    props.history.length = 1;
    window.location.replace(defaultPathname);
    props.history.push(defaultPathname);
  }
```

And here is a code sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-silence-47ztr

Remember that you can't reproduce it on desktop, only on mobile.

I checked several threads on StackOverflow like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30915173/react-router-go-back-a-page-how-do-you-configure-history), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084779/how-to-restrict-access-to-routes-in-react-router), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30915173/react-router-go-back-a-page-how-do-you-configure-history), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4) but I couldn't find a proper answer. Any help of how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `history.replace` (not push)

```js
if (!!matches) {
    const defaultPathname = `/event/${matches[1]}`;
    //props.history.length = 1; //<---- probably not required
    //window.location.replace(defaultPathname); //<---- not required
    props.history.replace(defaultPathname); //<---- like this
  }
```

**Edit**: Some explanation

The main difference between `push` and replace is that `push` will create a new entry in the browser’s history and `replace` will just replace the current state. This way you will not find the back button enabled.

**Some References**:

[1](https://florianherlings.de/posts/2020-04-22-history-javascript-pushstate/)

[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39340108/what-is-the-trade-off-between-history-push-and-replace)

[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507091/replacestate-vs-pushstate)

[4](https://reactrouter.com/web/api)

Comment: it seems like it's working, but why using `replace` instead of `push` fixed the issue? 

Comment: hope its all good now? can you please let me know if you have any qn..

Comment: it's working, thanks a lot @gdh I struggled for days with this issue, thanks!