# Go back to previous page regardless of changes in query string

Tags: javascript

I have a page with a searchable table. I have written a "Back" button to go back to the previous page:

```
<a href="javascript:history.back()">Back</a>
```

---

For example, the URL of my homepage is:

```
https://xxxxxx.com
```

I enter the page with a searchable table from my homepage ***(Or any other page)***:

```
https://xxxxxx.com/data
```

When I preform a search, the URL becomes:

```
https://xxxxxx.com/data?search=*sth*
```

When I hit the "Back" button, the URL becomes:

```
https://xxxxxx.com/data
```

What I actually want is:

```
https://xxxxxx.com/
```

***(Or the page where the user comes in before `/data`)***

---

**How can I rewrite my javascript on the search button, so that the Back button can get to the actual page?**

Comment: `<a href="https://xxxxxx.com/">Back</a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `history.back()`, which goes back only by one, you could do `window.location.replace(window.location.host)`, which loads the root page.

To get more info on `window.location`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

## Edit:

If you want to ignore URL parameters, you need to change how you go to another page.

Instead of `window.history.pushState(...)`, you should use `window.history.replaceState(...)`, when the navigation should be ignored on a back click.

Here more to read on that topic: [What is the trade off between history push and replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39340108/what-is-the-trade-off-between-history-push-and-replace)

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question. What if the page is not necessarily from the root?

Comment: I don't understand your question then. Please edit it to make it more clear what you are asking @samhoooo

Comment: I have edited the question, please check if it is clear for you. Basically I want to navigate back to the page before the user landed on /data, rather than a bit "hard coding" the root url.

Comment: Added more info to my answer @samhoooo